# Antd AutoComplete with suffix: how to avoid the opening of dropdown with suggested options when clicking on suffix component?

Tags: reactjs, input, autocomplete, antd, suffix

How to prevent opening the dropdown with suggested options when clicking on suffix component?

```
  ...

  const options = [{ value: "a" }, { value: "aa" }, { value: "aaa" }];

  const onClick = (e) => {
    console.log("Help");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  const Suffix = <div onClick={onClick}>Help</div>;

  return (
    <AutoComplete
      options={options}
      style={{ width: 200 }}
      onSelect={onSelect}
      onSearch={onSearch}
      onDropdownVisibleChange={(v) => console.log("onDropdownVisibleChange", v)}
    >
      <Input suffix={Suffix} />
    </AutoComplete>
  );
```

Use of "open" prop for controlling the dropdown state of AutoComplete component doesn't allow me to reach the goal: even though I set "open" to false into "onClick" handler, you can notice opening and closing animation of AutoComplete component when you click on "Help" ("onDropdownVisibleChange" is handled before "onClick").